# UDP transfer & maintaining network byte order

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp

So I am having some trouble sending and receiving a custom packet via a client-server program in C++. I have implemented something similar using TCP, however I am having issues converting everything into a single datagram when using UDP.

Currently I have the header consisting of an even number of uint32_t fields. Each of these is stored in network order like so in a header struct:

```
 uint32_t x = htonl (int y);
```

...

And I am combining the header with a payload in a packet like so:

```
 typedef struct {
    450Header header; // 512 bytes consisting of the unint32_t like above
    char data[ BLOCKSIZE ];  // 3.5k
    // Total Packet Size = 4k
} Packet;
```

'

The header portion will contain info about the packet, my question how to deal with byte order for strings and the payload. I would ideally like to add some string fields to the header for things like filename, and if I am sending a file larger than the blocksize in the packet I would like to split it up into multiple packets, I need to know how to split the file so it can be interpreted in the right order the receiving end.

1. I have successfully built a header independently (with all fields in network byte order), do i need to also convert the ordering of the strings if I add them to the header? I assume if i keep the strings at a set size I can still write a checksum function for the header.
2. If everything is correctly ordered from question 1, do I need to convert them again on the receiving end back to host order?
3. I have an mmap function which loads the file into a char buffer, can I simply copy this piece by piece to the data buffer in the Packet using something like memcpy and incrementing the offset? Or do I have to worry about network order for the payload data as well?
4. Do I need to use a checksum on the payload? And how do I do so if it does not use the whole buffer and ends up with an odd number of bytes?

Eventually I want the header to contain sequence number so I can practice implementing procedures if packets are dropped (i.e. go back N), so what I am most worried about is standardizing the order in which everything is sent from the client so it can be interpreted in the right order on the server side.

Answer (score 5):

8bit data (including 8bit integers, Ansi/UTF-8 strings, etc) do not suffer from byte order issues, so you can send/receive them as-is.  It is only multi-byte data (like 16bit/32bit integers, 16bit UCS2/UTF-16 strings, etc) that you have to deal with byte ordering.  For instance, integers should always be in network byte order, but UTF-16 strings can use either UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE at your discretion (though you should use UTF-8 instead).

If you have to split data into multiple packages, then you need to put information in the packet header to specify the order of the packets.  UDP does not guarantee packets arrive in the same order that they are sent, or even guarantee that they arrive at all.  So the receiver needs to collect the packets (requesting missing packets as needed) and then re-order them accordingly before then processing the data.

Yes, you should always convert packets to network byte order before sending them, and convert back to host byte order when processing them on the receiving end.  Converting to network byte order is only for transmission purposes to ensure a consistent format across platforms.

A checksum is a good idea to ensure the integrity of the data for each packet, but it is not a requirement.  You can certain provide a fixed-length checksum for arbitrary-length data, there are plenty of checksum algorithms that support that.